# Extension method that returns underlying type of generic argument

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I'm trying to write a extension method of `IThingRequest<TEntity>`, it returns `Thing<TEntity>`. I would like the method to only return the underlying type of `TEntity` not any other generic classes or interfaces it would implement. So, in the example below, the wish is that the return type should be `Thing<Entity>` not `Thing<GenericClass<Entity>>`.

The extensions method:

```
public static Thing<TEntity> DoStuff<TEntity>(IThingRequest<TEntity> request)
    => new Thing<TEntity>();
```

Calling the extension method:

```
public class Request : IThingRequest<GenericClass<Entity>>
{ }

var request = new Request();
var result = request.DoStuff();
```

The type of result is now `Thing<GenericClass<Entity>>`.

My first instinct was that there would be a way to achieve this with `where`, but I can't figure it out. I've also considered using reflections to get the non generic type of `TEntity` and returning `Thing<object>` but I believe that that would require casting where the `DoStuff` method is used.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why should it return the non generic class when you passed in a generic class? Can you show some example code that has some context so that it helps people understand what and why? I get what you are asking to some degree, but what are you trying to solve with this, maybe there's a better pattern?

Comment: `return` statement isn't need in expression body method, please post your actual code, the current will not compile

Comment: Thanks, missed that, removed the return!

Comment: Your'e right @Charleh, I was thinking about this wrong, instead of having `Request` implement `IThingRequest<GenericClass<Entity>>` I changed to implement both separately `GenericClass<Entity>, IThingRequest<Entity>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the input!

I wanted a solution where I didn't have to cast the result from `DoStuff` into `Thing<TEntity>`, like for instance casting `object`. Thanks to @Charleh I realised I was tackling the problem wrong and the solution was simply to implement both the class and interface separately like so:

```
public class Request : GenericClass<TEntity>, IThingRequest<Entity>
{ }
```

Comment: That even looks like it makes way more sense, glad you got it worked out, sometimes you just need to take a step back and come at it from another angle!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle nested generics and you know "wrapper" one you need to something like this:

```
public static Thing<T2> UnWrap<T1, T2>(IThingRequest<T1> request) 
       where T1: GenericClass<T2>
=> new Thing<T2>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see following variant of solution. GenericClass should implement IThingRequest. Then DoStuff extension method can be made reflectively recursive:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var request = new Request();
            var result = request.DoStuff();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static MethodInfo _doStaffMethodInfo;
        public static MethodInfo DoStaffMethodInfo => _doStaffMethodInfo = _doStaffMethodInfo ?? typeof(Program).GetMethod("DoStuff");

        public static object DoStuff<TEntity>(this IThingRequest<TEntity> request)
        {
            Type underlyingTypeOfTEntity = typeof(TEntity).GetInterface("IThingRequest`1")?.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            if (underlyingTypeOfTEntity != null)
            {
                MethodInfo doStaffMethodInfo = DoStaffMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(underlyingTypeOfTEntity);
                object thingRequest = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ThingRequest<>).MakeGenericType(underlyingTypeOfTEntity));
                return doStaffMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new []{thingRequest});
            }
            else
            {
                return new Thing<TEntity>();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IThingRequest<TEntity>
    {

    }

    public class GenericClass<TEntity> : IThingRequest<TEntity>
    {
    }

    public class Thing<TEntity>
    {
    }

    public class ThingRequest<TEntity> : IThingRequest<TEntity>
    {

    }

    public class Request : IThingRequest<GenericClass<Entity>>
    { }

    public class Entity
    {
    }
}
```